# iOS 15 / Safari - MediaStream not playing/black screen

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, ios15, peerjs

I'm creating a 1-1 calling application and seem to be encountering a problem with Safari ios15 to another safari mobile browser where the MediaStream is available but when attaching this to a `<video>` tag remains a black screen / nothing playing on the `<video>` element.

I am using PeerJS to establish a connection between the two and using `peer.call()` and `peer.answer()`

I am using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to start streams from both peers, this is working fine on all other devices with the exception of Safari on iOS 15.

I am also using setting the attributes for the `<video>` element to `playsinline` and `autoplay` with the addition of `muted` on the local stream, as other fixes have suggested but they have been no good.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with iOS 14.6 so i rebuilt my app in Flutter over a weekend with a few IPAs. Wasn't too difficult and had it live in both the app stores by the Tues afternoon. Helps if you port over keys too and copy any keyfiles across.

Docs are [here.](https://docs.flutter.dev/)

Remember, [expression closures have been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/%E2%80%A6).

I believe the issue is fixed in iOS 16.1, and was related to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` always throwing an `unassigned` in Safari. This happens to Chrome on iOS too as Apple force google to 'reskin' Safari in order to force the user into the ecosystem, and won't allow devs to use another engine. Worth a read up if you can, loads of articles across the web.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't be using safari. But if you're that way inclined, I'd use Brosix. What do you mean it doesn't work for iOS 15? Just use facetime. Alternatively, have you heard of Zoom app?

Comment: In an ideal world I wouldn't use safari either. The app I am building has a 1-1 video call feature, much like facetime to be built.

Answer (score 0):

The `video` element is deprecated. Just use `embed` instead.

```
<embed></embed>
```

Just like above.

Comment: Tried and this does not work, I am using the `<video>` which works fine for my local media stream. To clarify I am taking the Stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` and then attaching that to the `<video></video>` element, this works fine on everything but IOS15 iPhones... Do you mean that the `<video></video>` tag is deprecated on Safari/IOS devices?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `<embed></embed>` is deprecated.

Comment: Also, expression closures have been deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_expression_closures#:~:text=The%20JavaScript%20warning%20%22expression%20closures,the%20warning%20message%20is%20obsolete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you not just forgot to run composer?? Sometimes the problem can be overcomplicated, double check the simple stuff.